# Interrupted Advantage Play

Tags: rules, football, officiating

I am struggling to understand something about the advantage rule in football. What should happen when there is given advantage by the ref and after that there is a handball (talking about Ajax vs Chelsea). Should the ref give the first foul or the handball after the given advantage? What I have read so far, nothing is mentioned on that matter

Answer (score 1):

The referee could going back but only after a shortest time after foul is committed. It's not an official rule. It's left to the discretion of the referee

Answer (score 0):

When advantage is played, there is no "going back" to the first offence.

If a subsequent offence occurs, either that second offence is penalised as appropriate or it is again met with advantage.